# Team Build 2010 - Unable to access $(BuildNumber) from csproj file?

Tags: tfsbuild

The scenario is following:

1. I create myProject.csproj
2. In myProject.csproj xml in the AfterBuild target I want to access $(BuildNumber) variable
3. When I do the build with TFS 2008 everything works OK
4. When I migrate to TFS 2010 and use the DefaultBuildTemplate $(BuildNumber) always empty

Can you please provide the out of box solution - how to access this variable during build in TFS 2010?

The csproj file has the following code:

Answer (score 0):

The code in csproj file is following:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="MyBuildNumber $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)"></Message>
    <Message Text="MyVersionNumber $(MyVersionNumber)"></Message>
```